# Selenium python eror Conne

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to run python selenium tests in Jenkins CI. The python test works fine on a local end but not on the server. When I run on the server I get this error

```py
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
Test/UIFrontend/setupBrowser.py:35: in setupDriver
    driver.get("http://localhost:{0}/".format(port))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:333: in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7f1beb4312e8>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED\\n  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)","stacktrace":"#0 0x557fbae916a9 \\u003Cunknown>\\n"}}'}

    def check_response(self, response):
...
... 
...
...
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, message)
        elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
            alert_text = None
            if 'data' in value:
                alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
            elif 'alert' in value:
                alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
            raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
E         (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
```

```
"""Set up the webdriver to be used with other selenium tests.
"""
import os
import time

from selenium import webdriver


def setupDriver(options=None):
    """- Set up the webdriver to be used with other selenium tests.
    
    - Test fails if FRONT_PORT environment variable is not defined.

    - Loads Apollo and logs in

    Args:
        options (ChromeOptions, optional): Give custom ChromeOptions rather than using the one provided.

    Returns:
        webdriver: returns driver to be used with tests
    """
    if not options:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--headless') # have to be headless because of 

    if os.environ.get('FRONT_PORT'):
        port = str(os.environ.get('FRONT_PORT'))
    else:
        print("Environment variable FRONT_PORT not defined")
        assert False, "Environment variable FRONT_PORT not defined"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    print("http://localhost:{0}/".format(port)) 
    driver.get("http://localhost:{0}/".format(port)) #errors out here
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_id("username-input").send_keys("username")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password-input").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/" +
        "div/div/form/div[4]/button").click()
    return driver
```

I have no idea what this means. If you need more info please let me know. Also, the Jenkins CI is run on an external server meaning the tests have to be headless.

Answer (score 1):

The error is :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Meaning chrome couldn't connect to the website. This might be because the server cannot connect to the internet

you can recreate this exception in locat by turning of network and connecting to some website

[image]

SO verify whether jenkins CI have acceess to that website you are testing

Comment: Thanks that was very useful. I think it does because I am running docker image and it is localhost

Comment: @rodude123 could you accept and upvote if it helped

Comment: can't really accept as it didn't solve the issue. I know the server connects to the internet as it downloads from git and other online places

Comment: @rodude123 try running a simple ping command to the website you are trying from the server

Comment: the website is localhost

Comment: @rodude you cannot connect to localhost from jenkins server , you have to give netwokr ip  ( Only if the server is exposed in 0.0.0.0 address ) if it is exposed in 127.0.01 or any other localhost ip then it cannot be used for automation . If it is indeed exposed in internet address 0.0.0.0. then verify your firewall settings